# How to number blank even pages?

Tags: memoir, page-numbering

I have this kind of document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
```

however, the left blank pages due to the openright option are not numbered. For example, I am moving from page 5 to 7 since the page 6 is actually empty. How is it possible to let the page number appear on blank even pages ?

In other words, I want every page of my document to be numbered even if it is blank page

Comment: If you post the same question on more than one site, you should include links to all other versions of your question in all your questions!

Comment: just alias the `cleared` pagestyle to what ever style you want instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in the preamble:

```
\makeevenhead{empty}{\thepage}{}{}
```

The memoir package automatically switches to the pagestyle `empty' for these pages. The command works like this:

```
\makeevenhead{⟨style⟩}{⟨left⟩}{⟨center⟩}{⟨right⟩}
```

Commands `\makeoddhead`, `\makeevenfoot` and `\makeoddfoot` work alike.